# access compiled transcluded scope to calculate height of elements

Tags: angularjs

I have the following DOM:

```
<carousel calculate-carousel-height>
    <slide ng-repeat="article in bestArticles" active="slide.active">
        <div>{{article.text}}</div>
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

The `carousel` directive uses transcluded scope so I can get it in a linking function of my custom directive `calculate-carousel-height`:

```
link: function (scope, element, attributes, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
    transcludeFn(function( clonedTranscludedContent ) {
        // here I can access the transcluded scope
    });
}
```

However, the problem is that this scope is not yet compiled (ng-repeat directive hasn't been processed) so I don't have `article.text` and can't calculate height of the DOM containing the text. How and when can I access the transcluded scope after it's been compiled?

This will work but is it the best solution?

```
link: function (scope, element, attributes, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // angular finished its magic and I can access compiled transcluded DOM here
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `ng-repeat`, this is how I fixed it:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('article.text', function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the *transclude function* in this situation, maybe this is not the correct answer, but it may point you to the correct direction.